# How do I open my Excel sheets without VBA error message?

Tags: excel

Excel automatically updated last week. Every spreadsheet I open now comes up with error code Run-time error'53':

```
File not found:
/Library/Application/Application Support/Adobe/MACPDFM/MacPDF.framework/Versions/A/MacPDFM
```

Help and End buttons show. Help does not describe my problem.
Clicking End twice gets rids of the error message and the spreadsheet opens. I have no idea how to solve this. I am not a programmer and I have not changed any settings in Excel.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is off topic for SO. It's probably ok for other SE sites: superuser or askdifferent. I searched for "mac excel MacPDFM" and found things that look promising.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your Excelfile contains a macro, who tries to open the following file when you open an Excel worksheet:

```
/Library/Application/Application Support/Adobe/MACPDFM/MacPDF.framework/Versions/A/MacPDFM
```

When this file is not present, you get the mentioned error message.
Seen the structure of the directory, I believe the Excelfile only can be opened on a Mac-computer (Microsoft-computers don't have the mentioned directory structure).

Verify if you're working on a Mac-computer or a Windows-computer and in case of Mac, check the presence (and read permissions) of the mentioned file.

Comment: Yes I'm on a Mac and it is happening to every single excel spreadsheet. I have never set up or used macros in any of them.

Comment: Is the mentioned file present on your computer and do you have read access?

Comment: I've done a search through Finder but nothing coming up. Where should I look? But a Spotlight search opened Google and similar threads about this error.

Comment: No need to launch a search: if the file is not present at that exact location, you will have the error message. I would advise you trying to get that file and putting it on the exact location.

Comment: I have found a very simple solution from that Google thread that came up – Open Excel (or other MS app), go to Tools, Excel Add-ins, remove Save as PDF. (Different solution if it happens in Word.)